# Discord Invite Link -> Server ID

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I make the following code from a discord invite transfer into a server ID?

````
        guild_id = (await client.fetch_invite(invite)).with_counts
        if guild_id not in whitelist:
            print(f'{guild_id}')
    await client.process_commands(message)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I fixed it via `guild_id = getattr((await client.fetch_invite(invite)).guild, "id", None)`